# Ansible IP address variable remote hosts

Tags: python, shell, ansible, ip

I have the following problem:

I'm writing a playbook for configuring NFS server and NFS client.

in the same playbook, I include 2 other tasks :

CentOS_7_NFS_Server.yml and CentOS_7_NFS_Client.yml

for I can execute one of the tasks I need to compare the IP address of

the remote hosts

Example :

```
- include: CentOS_7_NFS_Server.yml
  when: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses == NFS_Server

- include: CentOS_7_NFS_Client.yml
  when:  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses == NFS_Client
```

in the var :

```
NFS_Server: x.x.x.x
NFS_Client : y.y.y.y
```

I got this error

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_all_ipv4.address 
== NFS_Client' failed. The error was: error while evaluating 
conditional (ansible_all_ipv4.address == NFS_Client): 
'ansible_all_ipv4' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been 
in
```

Comment: It's as the error says, `ansible_all_ipv4` is undefined. Maybe you meant to write `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`?

Comment: yes i mean ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very probably the collecting of the [facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gather_facts_module.html#gather-facts-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) is disabled. when you see the error:

> ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

Enable it

```
- hosts: nfs_server_and_client
  gather_facts: yes
```

There is one more problem. *ansible_all_ipv4_addresses* is **list** of **all** addresses. For example.

```
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 192.168.122.1
  - 10.1.0.11
  - 192.168.1.10
```

You'll have to pick one, or more and assign it to *NFS_Server* and *NFS_Client*. Then the condition shall [test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#other-operators) if *NFS_Server* and *NFS_Client*, respectively,  is in the list *ansible_all_ipv4_addresses*.

```
- include: CentOS_7_NFS_Server.yml
  when: NFS_Server in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

- include: CentOS_7_NFS_Client.yml
  when: NFS_Client in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir . just one question how I can pick one ip address from the list that it's same in my var.   Example NFS_Server: 192.168.122.1

Comment: I mean, you'll have to pick and assign an address to the NFS_Server and  NFS_Client. This depends on the architecture of the network. It can be tested if NFS_Server is present in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses. `when: NFS_Server in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`. I've updated the answer.